# A Google matrix equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I would like to understand the matrix equation $(4)$ on the page $95$ [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.450.1721&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
concerning some Google matrix computations.
I got this far:

$$||x(t)||=||dWx(t-1)||+\frac{||x(t-1)||-||dWx(t-1)||}{N}\cdot N=||x(t-1)||\ {\stackrel{\mbox{?}}{=}}\ 1,$$
but why this last is $= 1$ ?

Comment: (2) is just the compact writing of (1), whcih itself is just formalization of the idea in the paragraph above it

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You mention $(2)$ and $(1)$ but I've asked for $(4)$.

Comment: @BlueEyedDaisy This is what I did in the last but one line in my OQ but I've end up with $$||x(t-1)||\ {\stackrel{\mbox{?}}{=}}\ 1.$$ Could you do that calculation in some detail for me ?

Comment: That last one is not $N$, it is $\mathbf 1_N$, so there is some difference in your interpretation and the intended meaning.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон The last one is $\mathbf 1_N$ so it is equal to $\frac{||x(t-1)||-||dWx(t-1)||}{N} \cdot N$ (i.e. the sum of $N$ $\frac{||x(t-1)||-||dWx(t-1)||}{N}$). But this is finally $||x(t-1)||$.

Comment: @user3357120 I think I will get to the bottom of this and write an answer.

Comment: @user3357120 I think I understood. Look, the argument  to show that $\|x(t)\|_1 = 1$ for all $t$, is by *induction*. So, we start with any choice of $\mathbf x(0)$ such that $\mathbf x(0) = 1$, to get the base case (not mentioned, but has to be). The above computation (except for the last equal to) shows that $\|\mathbf x(t)\|_1 = \|\mathbf x(t-1)\|_1$, so if for an induction step we assumed that $\|\mathbf x(t-1)\|_1 = 1$, then $\|\mathbf x(t)\|_1 = 1$ as well. Therefore, by mathematical induction, we conclude the statement $\|\mathbf x(t)\|_1 = 1$ for all $t$.

Comment: That ensures that $\mathbf x$ which satisfies the PageRank system of Brin ( $\mathbf x$ will be the pointwise system of $\mathbf x(t)$), then also has $\|\mathbf x\|_1 = 1$.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон Your answer is just perfect!

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон But I thought that $t$ is time. Is it discrete rather than continuous ??

Comment: It is discrete and going to infinity.

Comment: You should read up the Banach fixed point theorem. See , to prove the existence of a solution to the problem, you start with any starting vector and repeatedly apply the function. If the function is what is called as a contraction, then you will reach a solution. Applying the function to the vector at time t gives you a vector at time t+1. Since function application is discrete, we have discrete time as well.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Please, see my comment below your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is of low quality and only attracts low quality answers as we could see today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting up my comments above as an answer.

Basically, equation $4$ specifies an iterative scheme to find the *fixed point* of the PageRank equation specified by Brin et al., and it works along the lines of the *Banach fixed point theorem*.

That is, given the equation (on vectors) $\mathbf x = d\mathbf{Wx} + \frac{\|\mathbf x\|_1 - \|d\mathbf{Wx}\|_1}{N}\mathbf{1}_N$  , we take our function $f(\mathbf x) = d\mathbf{Wx} + \frac{\|\mathbf x\|_1 - \|d\mathbf{Wx}\|_1}{N}\mathbf{1}_N$ and form a sequence like so : take any starting vector $\mathbf x(0)$ so that $\|\mathbf x(0)\|_1 = 1$. Now define $\mathbf x(t) = f(\mathbf x(t-1))$ : so you keep applying $f$ to what you get. The calculations you make show by *induction* that $\|\mathbf x(t)\|_{1} = 1$ for all $t$.

This gives a sequence of vectors $\{\mathbf x(t)\}_{t=0,1,2,...}$, and the point is, under conditions given by the Banach FPT, this converges to a solution vector $\mathbf x$, which will satisfy $\mathbf x = f(\mathbf x)$, the PageRank equation.

Why is that? Well, you kept applying $f$ again and again : suppose that $f$ was a contraction i.e. it tended to bring two points *closer* upon applying $f$ on each of them. Then, repeated application of $f$ keeps bringing the functions values closer to each other, and finally we come to a point where applying $f$ doesn't change the point (which is a fixed point). The condition $d <1$ ensures that Banach FPT applies, giving a solution. Thus, existence and uniqueness of solution is given by the Banach FPT.

Furthermore, by closure, that solution will also satisfy $\|\mathbf x\|_1 = 1$, which is desirable to Brin, I would think.

Comment: Which page and line [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.450.1721&rep=rep1&type=pdf) says that  $$||x(0)||_1=1$$ ?

Comment: @user3357120 No line or page in that document says it : the thing is, you can see from the vagueness of the whole document that all details won't be necessarily specified (that's why you asked me this question!) . The point is, the calculation above shows that $\|x(t)\| = \|x(t-1)\|$ for all $t > 0$, but you can't get $\|x(t)\| = 1$ for all $t$, unless $\|x(0)\| = 1$, so this had to be the case.